# What method to connect to the database is better?

Tags: java, jdbc

I have a problem with the heap memory. I have my application running on a Wildfly server. One of my applications uses a class to create the connection to the database.

The structure of the class is like this.

```
public class Operations{
    private static Connection con;
    static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Operations.class);

    private static void setConnection() {


        try {

            con =DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://server.domain.net:1111;databaseName=DATA","user","pass");//cap

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            logger.debug(e.getLocalizedMessage());
        } 
    }

    public static Contract validateContract(String contractNumber) {
        logger.debug("Entre validad");
        try {
            Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
            logger.debug("Entre al metodo");
            setConnection();
            CallableStatement proc_stmt = con.prepareCall("{call database.storeProName(?)}");
            proc_stmt.setString(1, contractNumber);

            Contract contract = new Contract();
            ResultSet rs = proc_stmt.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {
                contract.setValid(rs.getInt(1));
                contract.setContractID(rs.getInt(2));
                contract.setMessage(rs.getString(3));
            }

            return contract;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Contract contmp = new Contract();
            contmp.setMessage(e.getMessage());
            contmp.setValid(0);
            return contmp;
        }
    }

.
.
.
public static Contract validateContract2(String contractNumber) {
        logger.debug("Entre validad");
        try {
            Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
            logger.debug("Entre al metodo");
            setConnection();
            CallableStatement proc_stmt = con.prepareCall("{call database.storeProName(?)}");
            proc_stmt.setString(1, contractNumber);

            Contract contract = new Contract();
            ResultSet rs = proc_stmt.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {
                contract.setValid(rs.getInt(1));
                contract.setContractID(rs.getInt(2));
                contract.setMessage(rs.getString(3));
            }

            return contract;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Contract contmp = new Contract();
            contmp.setMessage(e.getMessage());
            contmp.setValid(0);
            return contmp;
        }
    }
}
```

This class is used for all the JSP that I have in the project. I don´t know if I should change the code to be a non-static class. Also I should be closing the connection, but I´m not sure if I should close the connection for a static method.

Comment: Since you are using Wildfly then just define your datasource there and use its connection pool. BTW google around for proper JDBC access code and see what you need to close in `finally` block.

Comment: I second @tsolakp, without connection pool each validateContract adds another connection.  No wonder your heap is growing out of bounds.  Didn't you check a heapdump?

Comment: I am configuring JAVA to allow remote connections to monitore the heap memory of my applications. But I don´t know which application is consumming the memory because of wildfly is one proccess, I can´t see where are the WARs with VisualVM.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille. Do you think that closing the connection at the end of each method will help the increasing of the heap memory?

Comment: It is better to use a connection pool and to only ever have `Connection`, `Statement`, `PreparedStatement`, `ResultSet` etc. as local variables, all closed on exit from the method. Any design where any of them is a static or instance member is immediately suspect, on thread-safety grounds alone, and also on resource-leak grounds.

Comment: You probabley want no help increasing the heap, on the contrary. Closing might prevent the heap from growing, but there's no guarantee.  In theory, Java should garbage collect the connections once you're done with them, but they are complex object, and there might be dependencies or bugs in drivers which prevent collection.  Do as tsolakp, EJP and probably the Wildfly documentation says: use a connection pool.  Your mileage will increase (but watch it, you may still run into trouble).  Did you examine a heapdump now?